# OpenSSL: I encrypt and decrypt files with RSA keys that I have stored con external files, but sometimes my program chrashes

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I encrypt and decrypt files with RSA keys that I generate and store in ".bin" files (it also works storing them in ".txt" files).  Now, I read the keys from those files and encrypt/decrypt a message. My program crashes sometimes due to bad memory allocation. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
#define RSA_KEY_LENGTH 2048
#define PUB_EXP     3

#define PRIVFILE "rsa_privkey_file.bin"
#define PUBFILE "rsa_pubkey_file.bin"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Generate a pair of keys and store them in different files

    RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(RSA_KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);
    printf("Comprobando par de claves (Si son buenas 1): %i \n",RSA_check_key(keypair));

    FILE *rsa_pubkey_file = fopen(PUBFILE,"wb");
    FILE *rsa_privkey_file = fopen(PRIVFILE,"wb");

    int temp;
    temp = PEM_write_RSAPublicKey(rsa_pubkey_file, keypair);
    fflush(rsa_pubkey_file);
    fclose(rsa_pubkey_file);

    temp = PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(rsa_privkey_file, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, 0,NULL);
    fflush(rsa_privkey_file);
    fclose(rsa_privkey_file);
    printf("claves generadas..\n\n");

    // DONE GENERATING!

    // ENCRYPTION with public key readed from its correspondent file

    int retval = 0;
    RSA *rsa_pubkey = NULL;
    rsa_pubkey_file = fopen(PUBFILE,"rb");
    rsa_privkey_file = fopen(PRIVFILE,"rb");

    if (PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(rsa_pubkey_file, &rsa_pubkey, NULL, NULL) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "HORROR!!! loading RSA Public Key File.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        retval = 2;
    } //key read

    printf("size de keypair (asumo que sera 8 siempre): %lu\n", sizeof(keypair));

    char msg[2048/8] = "1234567A1234567B1234567C1234567D";
    printf("msg: %s\n", msg);
    printf("size msg (asumo 256): %lu\n", sizeof(msg));
    unsigned char * encrypt = (unsigned char*)malloc(8);

    temp = RSA_public_encrypt((int)strlen(msg), (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)encrypt, rsa_pubkey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    printf("size encrypt(asumo 256):    %i\n", temp);

    // DONE ENCRYPTING!

    // DECRYPT with private key readed from its correspondent file

    RSA *rsa_prikey = NULL;

    if (PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(rsa_privkey_file, &rsa_prikey, NULL, NULL) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "HORROR!!! loading RSA Public Key File.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        retval = 2;
    } //key read

    char * decrypt = (char*)malloc(8);
    temp = RSA_private_decrypt(256, (unsigned char*)encrypt, (unsigned char*)decrypt,rsa_prikey , RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    printf("size decrypt (asumo 32):    %i\n", temp);
    printf("decrypted: %s\n", msg);

    //DONE DECRYPTING!

    free(keypair);
    free(rsa_pubkey);
    free(rsa_prikey);
    fclose(rsa_privkey_file);
    fclose(rsa_pubkey_file);
    free(encrypt);
    free(decrypt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Joe It crashes just before the RSA_public_encrypt(...). I got this error message: RSA_bin(9027,0x7fff71f52310) malloc: *** error for object 0x10060a348: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: @Joe It also crashes before the RSA_private_decrypt(...) sometimes..

Comment: Does it crash with both .bin and .txt files, or just with .txt files?  Do you convert the raw bytes to/from Base64 when using .txt files?

Comment: It really has something to do with the error. When I use .txt files the program is more likely to crash. How do I convert my bytes to Base64? (I would like to try it) Will this cause problems when using "PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(...)" and "PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(...)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char msg[2048/8] = "1234567A1234567B1234567C1234567D";
printf("msg: %s\n", msg);
printf("size msg (asumo 256): %lu\n", sizeof(msg));
unsigned char * encrypt = (unsigned char*)malloc(8);
```

This buffer seems pretty small to hold the results of the encryption of your source message.

Comment: Yep, that is a bug. OP should [RTFM](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_private_decrypt)

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory error. You can use Clang (or another memory tool) to check for problems at runtime.

Here's the command line for building your program with Clang 3.3 and two sanitizers:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/clang -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -DDEBUG=1 -O1 -g3
  -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -I/usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/include test-openssl.c
  -o test-openssl.exe /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/lib/libcrypto.a
```

Here's the result:

```
$ ./test-openssl.exe | asan_symbolize.py 
=================================================================
==7693==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000007118 at pc 0x10d86b0ff bp 0x7fff524bd560 sp 0x7fff524bcd20
WRITE of size 32 at 0x602000007118 thread T0
    #0 0x10d86b0fe (/usr/local/lib/clang/3.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib+0xc0fe)
    #1 0x10d777237 (/Users/jwalton/./test-openssl.exe+0x100035237)
    #2 0x10d7749b4 (/Users/jwalton/./test-openssl.exe+0x1000329b4)
    #3 0x10d7432b4 (/Users/jwalton/./test-openssl.exe+0x1000012b4)
    #4 0x7fff888ff7e0 (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x27e0)
    #5 0x0
0x602000007118 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x602000007110,0x602000007118)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x10d86ecd5 (/usr/local/lib/clang/3.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib+0xfcd5)
    #1 0x10d743279 (/Users/jwalton/./test-openssl.exe+0x100001279)
    #2 0x7fff888ff7e0 (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x27e0)
    #3 0x0
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1c0400000dd0: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000de0: fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000df0: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000e00: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000e10: fa fa 00 fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
=>0x1c0400000e20: fa fa 00[fa]fa fa 00 fa fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd
  0x1c0400000e30: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000e40: fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000e50: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000e60: fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400000e70: fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa fd fd
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap right redzone:    fb
  Freed heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==7693==ABORTING
```

Valgrind may be able to help (but I've found OpenSSL's sloppiness pretty much neutralizes it).

You can find instructions on downloading, build and installing Clang 3.4 at [Dynamic Analysis with Clang](https://docs.python.org/devguide/clang.html). Its a recipe based HowTo for developers.